# Run external vbs file, in js function

Tags: javascript, vbscript

What I need, is that after the browser check is done, if it's IE, the js function will call the .vbs file, and then run it...I've googled for some time, and I didn't find something that helped solving this case...Can someone give me any tips?

This is the actual script:

```
<script>
function verify(){
    var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;

    if(!is_chrome)
    {
        var retVal = confirm("run vbs to proceed");
        if( retVal == true ){
      alert("User wants to continue!");
      return true;

        }else{
      alert("User does not want to continue!");
      return false;}
    }  
    else
    {
        window.location.href = "destination.html";
    }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<a onclick="verify()">Link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this meant to be an HTA? Web browsers do not have the authority to launch client-side applications.

Comment: i would like to not use ActiveX elements

Answer (score 0):

Create a wshshell.run to run. You must navigate to a local html page to do things like this to avoid security issues.